# modify an existing object to match an updated version of that object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, recursion

In JavaScript, I have an object.  Changes to that object are being tracked (I'm using AngularJS).

In my Service in AngularJS, I am getting an updated version of that object.  I don't know what has changed about it, I don't know the model of this object, I just know that:

1) These two objects have the same model (Although arrays within the model may have increased or decreased in size)

2) If I change the reference of my old object to the new one, AngularJS will (understandably) not be able to update the front end to reflect the new object, because all of the watches on the old object just broke.

So, I thought "Well, I will just copy all of the values from the updated object over to the new one! "  This works remarkably well.  however, I am having trouble getting my formula just right, So I thought I would ask for a bit of help.  note that these are complex objects of an unknown, albeit identical, model:

```
 var makeEqual = function(originalObject, updatedObject){
    for (var key in originalObject) {
        if (typeof originalObject[key] == "object"
            && originalObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            makeEqual(originalObject[key], updatedObject[key]);
        }
        else{
            originalObject[key] = updatedObject[key];
        }
    };       
}
```

However, so far I have the following problem.  If `updateObject` is an array, new elements will not be added. deleted elements won't be removed, either (I think, not sure about that).  Note that the array could be an array of child objects.

To be honest, I feel like there are toher problems that this might have other than what I have detected myself, so I ask:  How can I create this "deep copy to an existing object" function work perfectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

angular has this built in.  Try:

```
angular.copy(updatedObject, originalObject);
```

This will do a lovely deep copy, replacing everything on the original object.

Comment: You, sir, are a gentleman and a scholar.  I can't believe I didn't know that existed.